# Force Kestrel to specified port

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I will ask my question first and then I will explain why.

How can I specify that my Kestrel server shouldn't listen to the port that .Net Core Module tells it to?

I have this web api application written in .Net Core and it's using some micro service architecture. The final web application exposes some APIs over the net for the clients to use but it will have to expose some special APIs internally to be used by the micro services.

Now I start two Kestrel services on two different ports using the code bellow and specifying two different ports:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args, ServerSettings settings)
{
    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseKestrel(
        (options) => AttachEndPoints(options, settings.HttpBindingPort)).
        UseStartup<HttpStartup>().Build();
}

protected static void AttachEndPoints(KestrelServerOptions options, int? port)
{
    var ip = IPAddress.Any;
    options.Listen(ip, port ?? 80)
}
```

This works great running as a Console application and everything works fine. But, when I start the application in IIS using ASP.Net Core Module, the listening port of the ASP.Net Core Module overrides my own specified port and both Http end points try to bind to the same random port causing the system to fail to start.

Comment: Create two different virtual directories in IIS and make them listen to the ports that you want.

Comment: @RacilHilan What do you mean by two virtual directories? Do you mean two different websites?

Comment: Yes, two different websites.

Comment: That way I can't pass information between them. This will make two application (instances) that can't communicate

Comment: You didn't mention such a requirement in your question. You can pass information between two different websites in several ways (database, HTTP request parameters, etc). The problem is that IIS is the one that decides the IP and port of each website. You can use Kestrel directly without IIS if you like, and that will make it work exactly like in your console app experiment. However, using Kestrel alone without IIS is not recommended for public-facing websites because Kestrel is a basic server that doesn't have all the powerful features of IIS. It is probably OK for simple non-critical websites

Comment: Why do you need IIS? What features do you need?